# how to fit multiselector in extjs fit to screen

Tags: extjs

I am new to extjs, and the width in multiselector can only be specified in pixels, not by percentage.

As a result of this, my multiselector is stretching differently depending on screen resolution.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

you should use the layout: 'fit' config for the parent container.

you can refer the following example for the sample usage.

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
title: 'Fit Layout',
width: 300,
height: 150,
layout:'fit',
items: {
    title: 'Inner Panel',
    html: 'This is the inner panel content',
    bodyPadding: 20,
    border: false
},
renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

hope this helps.
Thanks.